# How to get detailed error message on Shiny?

Tags: shiny, bookmarks

I'm new to Shiny and I keep getting this error without any explanation "Error bookmarking state:". How can I learn more about the error in my local server?[Shiny Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktGYd.png)

My app has a bit complicated workflow which means it goes to another tab if you hit certain buttons, so I made the bookmark move to the next tab and that's when it started giving the empty error message. It's working correctly, so the error message is annoying.

```
SEND {"notification":{"type":"show","message":{"html":"Error bookmarking state: ","action":"","deps":[],"duration":null,"closeButton":true,"id":"93ba934b2c3d270a","type":"error"}}}

SEND {"errors":[],"values":{"sampleSelector":{"html":"<div class=\"form-group shiny-input-container\">\n  <label class=\"control-label\" for=\"samples\">Samples</label>\n  <div>\n    <select id=\"samples\" multiple=\"multiple\"><option value=\"ALAB.rep1\" selected>ALAB.rep1</option>\n<option value=\"ALAB.rep2\" selected>ALAB.rep2</option>\n<option value=\"ALAB.rep3\" selected>ALAB.rep3</option>\n<option value=\"J1c.rep1\" selected>J1c.rep1</option>\n<option value=\"J1c.rep2\" selected>J1c.rep2</option>\n<option value=\"J1c.rep3\" selected>J1c.rep3</option>\n<option value=\"J2c.rep1\" selected>J2c.rep1</option>\n<option value=\"J2c.rep2\" selected>J2c.rep2</option>\n<option value=\"J2c.rep3\" selected>J2c.rep3</option>\n<option value=\"chow.wt.rep1\" selected>chow.wt.rep1</option>\n<option value=\"chow.wt.rep2\" selected>chow.wt.rep2</option>\n<option value=\"chow.wt.rep3\" selected>chow.wt.rep3</option>\n<option value=\"hfd.ALAB.rep1\" selected>hfd.ALAB.rep1</option>\n<option value=\"h... <truncated>
```

So I might have located the issue. Normally Dataset() doesn't give an issue, but it gives the error right after restoring in the onbookmark function. I tried an if condition with is null or is initialized for Dataset but it didn't work.

```
onBookmark(function(state) {
    cat("on bookmark", "\n")
    state$values$data <- Dataset()
    cat("on bookmark2", "\n")
....
}
```

Comment: You can start by [checking the documentation](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#bookmark_state_dir) or providing us with some code or logs showing what exactly you are trying to do and what exactly is causing your errors. Good luck

Comment: Ruslan, thank you for responding! The issue is the particular error doesn't show up in the Rstudio console when I'm running the application. It just produces a red box in the bottom corner saying "Error bookmarking state:" I don't know how to get a more detailed error message.

Comment: Can you try creating a small app that reproduces the error?

Comment: Using options(shiny.trace=TRUE), I got a little more details on the error, and I'm updating my question.